# Не обновляется фрагмент после обновления gradle

Tags: java, android

Мне пришлось обновить свой проект для дальнейшей работы. Gradle обновился с 4.8.1 на 5.1.1. Далее перевел проект на androidx через refactor. Все вроде бы удачно обновилось и безошибочно. Сразу запустил приложение и оказалось, что теперь у меня не обновляется фрагмент, когда мне надо.

MyFragment:

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == Code && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                    "Это уведомление удачно выводится, значит не работает лишь обновление", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
            reLoadFragment();
        }
    }

    public void reLoadFragment() {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.detach(this).attach(this).commit();
    }
```

До обновления проекта, все работало удачно. При закрытии активности, запускаемой с фрагмента, фрагмент обновлялся. Сейчас же мне не могут помочь ни один пример в интернете. Множество примеров перепробовал. Ошибок не вылетает, но обновления не происходит. Был бы рад любому ответу, хочется разобраться в этой проблеме. Может быть какие-то решения устарели и надо что-то заменить? Если вдруг понадобится дополнительный код, могу скинуть. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, теперь это не работает, согласно [доке](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/transactions#attach-detach):

> As a FragmentTransaction is treated as a single atomic set of operations, calls to both detach and attach on the same fragment instance in the same transaction effectively cancel each other out, thus avoiding the destruction and immediate recreation of the fragment's UI. Use separate transactions, separated by executePendingOperations() if using commit(), if you want to detach and then immediately re-attach a fragment.

Соответственно, надо отдельные транзакции запускать, чтобы операции транзакции не перезатирали друг друга. Например [так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65323308/3212712):

```
parentFragmentManager.beginTransaction().detach(this).commit ()
parentFragmentManager.beginTransaction().attach(this).commit ()
```

Ну а ещё лучше - обновлять фрагменты правильно, подписав их на какое-то событие каким-то способом.

Comment: Благодарю за ваш ответ

Comment: Это стало моим решением проблемы. Проверка прошла успешно!